# Extract strings only from a line in php

Tags: php, string, explode

I am using explode to extract only strings from a whole line. However using this:

```
$array = explode(" ", $line);
```

It splits the line by only one space, not by words. For example if $line is

```
$line="word1  word2    word3"
```

then I also have spaces among the entries in the array (it contains: "word1", "word2" and "word3", but also one or two " ").

Does anyone know how to obtain only the three entries "word1", "word2" and "word3" in the array ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) , to split on one or more whitespace characters:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
```

Unlike `explode` (which splits on a string), `preg_split` splits on a regular expression, so it is more flexible. If you don't need to use a regular expression for your delimiter, you should instead use `explode`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) with a format code or 1 or 2, and a char list indicating that digits should be considered part of the word, because this will also handle splitting against punctuation marks

```
$array = str_word_count($line, 1, '0123456789');
```

Comment: One of the oft-forgotten PHP functions, because most people scanning it in the docs will only see it as a way fo counting frequency of words (the `0` default format code argument).... the biggest drawback is that it isn't binary-safe

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use **Tom Fenech's** answer but for your existing code:

```
$array = array_filter(explode(" ", $line));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove empty array values with array filter:

```
 $array = array_filter(explode(" ", $line));
```